# How to access a file given the absolute url of a SharePoint document via Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

Is there any way to access a file given the absolute url of a SharePoint document via Graph (or rest)? For example, how would I download a file with the absolute url "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/test/Docs/Documents/Folder/file.docx" or "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/team1/teams/team2/Shared%20Documents/Folder/Folder2/file.pptx"
 as a stream?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754732/download-sharepoint-file-from-microsoft-graph-api-using-sourcedoc-id